# Why output of *(arr + k) != *(&arr + k) although both refereed to same address

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying t print the content of array. Please find the code.

```
int main(){
    int k = 2;
    int arr[5] = {8,7,5,11,2};
    printf("arr   %p\n", arr);
    printf("&arr  %p\n", &arr);
    printf("*(arr + k)    %p\n", *(arr + k));
    printf("*(&arr + k)   %p\n", *(&arr+k));
}
```

I'm getting below output for above program where arr + k and &arr + k must be same.

```
arr   0x7ffe4e76ab60
&arr  0x7ffe4e76ab60
*(arr + k)    0x5
*(&arr + k)   0x7ffe4e76ab88
```

Comment: Check `sizeof(arr)` and `sizeof(&arr)` and you will see. First one is array type, the second one is a pointer type.

Answer (score 3):

> `arr + k` and `&arr + k` must be same

They are not the same.

In `arr + k`, advance `k` steps (each with size equal to `sizeof *arr`) and yield a value of the same type as decayed `arr` (`int*`).

In `&arr + k`, advance `k` steps (each with size equal to `sizeof arr`) and yield a value of the same type as `&arr` (`int(*)[5]`).

The step size is different in the 2 expressions. First it's the size of each element; second it's the size of the whole array.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions `arr` and `&arr` evaluate to the same address, but they have different types:

```
 arr - int *
&arr - int (*)[5];
```

Pointer arithmetic takes the size of the pointed-to type into account, so `arr + 1` evaluates to the address of the next `int`, while `&arr + 1` evaluates to the address of the next *5-element array of `int`*.

```
         +----+
arr[0] : |  8 | <--- arr, &arr
         +----+
arr[1] : |  7 | <--- arr + 1
         +----+
arr[2] : |  5 |
         +----+
arr[3] : | 11 |
         +----+
arr[4] : |  2 |
         +----+
         | ?? | <--- &arr + 1
         +----+
         | ?? |
         +----+
         | ?? |
         +----+
         | ?? |
         +----+
         | ?? |
         +----+
```

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is (by definition) the address of the first element (so it is a pointer to the base type of the array, in this case `int`), while `&arr` is the address of the array, so it is of type `int[5]*` (a pointer to an array of 5 `int`s).  When you use `(arr + 5)` you are computing (pointer arithmetic) the value of a pointer to `int` and moving it 5 places up (5 times the size of an `int`).  When you say `(&arr + 5)` you are computing the value of a pointer to `int[5]` and moving it 5 times the size of an array of 5 `int`s.  This is five times what you move the previous pointer. This makes both addresses different, as the pointed types are of different sizes.  The result values will be also different (the `*(arr + 5)` is the value pointed to at the fifth position of the array, while `*(&arr + 5)` is the value (an array of 5 `int`s) positioned 25 `int`s further in the memory, but as an array, when deferred gives the address of the first element, you'll get the value of the integer stored 25 places higher in memory.